# How does SVM classify work?

Tags: c++, classification, svm

I am absolutely new to SVM or any of these classification techniques. Now i was learning how to use SVM-multiclass to classify data, and I am confused:

I understand perfectly how the svm-learn works on the training data, by creating hyperplanes and stuff, and finding support-vectors.

What I dont seem to get is how svm-classify works, or rather, What is its actual function?
From its name, svm-classify should "assign classes to the unclassified points" but it seems to just give me the "error" and "average-loss" on test set.

to be more clear :

if i train the svm with this file:

```
class-label : data
```

and then i pass the test file like this:

```
    data1
    data2
    .
    .
    dataN
```

so svm_classify should output the classes to these data...

Shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `svm-light` but not `libsvm`.
After you train the data, you should have a model file.
Then you run the svm_classify as follows:

```
svm_classify [options] example_file model_file output_file
```

The classification result should be written in `output_file`.